# decrease image width when browser width decrease

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem with a webpage that has an image to the left and content area to the right with a fixed width.
When I decrease the width on the browser I will decrease the width of the image, BUT not make it smaller. I will cut it from the left side.

How can I do this?

Comment: Show your markup and css. Is this an `img` element or a background image?

Comment: I don't want to resize the image, I will have the same height and make the width smaller but cutting the image from left, make the visible area smaller.

Answer (score 1):

Adding following to image's css will do the trick

```
.image-left-of-content{
   background-size : contain;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi here i give you an example, you make the .left div 20% of the container and the img inside 100% of the left div, so if you resize the page this should work

html

```
<div class="container">
       <div class="left">
          <img src="...your image src"/>
       </div>
       <div class="right">
         content
       </div>
    </div>
```

css

```
.container{width: 400px;}
.left{width: 20%;}
.left img{width: 100%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly I'd suggest you should set percentage widths to your image and content areas.

See this example http: //jsfiddle.net/0z063thv/